# Can 32-Bit PHP run a .vbs script on a 64-Bit IIS Server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, com

There is a vbscript that we must run to consolidate information gathered in a custom web application into our management software. The .vbs is in the same folder as the web application which is built in CodeIgniter 2.

Here is the controller code:

```
public function saveToPM( $budgetType ){
    // run it 
    $obj = new COM( 'WScript.Shell' ); 

    if ( is_object ( $obj ) ) { 
        $obj->Run( 'cmd /C wscript.exe D:\pamtest\myload.vbs', 0, true );
        var_dump($obj->Run);
    } else { 
        echo 'can not create wshell object'; 
    } // end if

    $obj = null;

    //$this->load->view('goodPush');
} // end saveToPM function
```

We have enabled DCon in the php.ini file and used dcomcnfg to enable permissions for the user.

I borrowed the code from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?505709-run-a-vbs-from-php.

The screen echos "Code executed" but the vbscript does not run.

We have been fighting with this for a while so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: does the VBS run directly from command line?

Comment: You're not checking if the code actually executed by checking the $obj->run's return value. you're just assuming it did and echoing as such.

Comment: I can double-click the vbs on the server and run it from the command line and in both cases, it works correctly.

Comment: Marc B, you are correct. In previous attempts with other code, we would get the white screen and the screen would hang so I just put a check to see if the code got beyond the call. I don't know how to check if the code actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit messy. PHP calls `WScript.Shell.Run` which will call `cmd` (with `/c` - i.e terminate `cmd.exe` when it's done its thing) which will call `cscript.exe` to run and interpret a `.vbs`. As you can see quite a few things that have to go right! :)

What if you 'wait' for the `WScript.Shell.Run` call to end (your `$wait` variable) before continuing execution of the wsh script which will in turn allow PHP to continue execution etc?

Since you're not waiting for the call to finish, PHP thinks its all good and continues onto the next line (interpreted language).

Also, maybe have the `.vbs` create an empty text file? Just so you have an indication that it has actually run.

Just take a step back, have a beer and it'll come to you! Gogo troubleshoot!

And - http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

> If bWaitOnReturn is set to TRUE, the Run method returns any error code returned by the application.

Comment: The last bit is if you wanna actually check the result of the `$obj->run` as Marc B suggested. If wait is not set to true the `Run` call will always return 0.

Comment: Spyros, I changed the code to what I think you are suggesting. However, I just get a white screen and control never returns.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code with a stand-alone PHP script (without Codeigniter) on a Windows XP machine, with the PHP 5.4.4 built-in web server, and I've noticed that the vbscript gets executed, but PHP dies (the event viewer shows a generic "Application Error" with ID 1000).
However I've also discovered that removing the "cmd /C" from the command string solves the problem.
Here is the simple script that I've used for my test:

```
<?php

$obj = new COM('WScript.Shell');
if (is_object($obj)) {
  //$obj->Run('cmd /C wscript.exe test.vbs', 0, true);  // This does'nt work
  $obj->Run('wscript.exe test.vbs', 0, true);   // This works
  var_dump($obj->Run);
} else {
  echo 'can not create wshell object';
}
$obj = null;

?>
```

And this is my simple "test.vbs" script:

```
WScript.Echo "vbscript is running"
```

Another solution that seems to be working (at least on my platform) is the "system" call:

```
system('wscript.exe test.vbs');
```

Unfortunately I don't have a 64-bit IIS system to test with, so I can't really say if there are specific problems on this platform, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Your first option returns "object(com_safearray_proxy)#28 (0) { }" and the system option spins out a white page with no warnings or errors.

Comment: @jgravois Thanks for the feedback. Did you check for errors in you event log or in the IIS log?

Comment: @jgravois Maybe [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) could give some clues about the problem. Apply a filter to display only the "wscript.exe" activity, then search for failed accesses to the registry or the filesystem.